# Wiring Akka PoisonPill to actor system and JVM shutdown hooks

Tags: java, java-8, akka

Akka/**Java** here, although I have a basic understanding of Scala. New to Akka. I have a `Master` class that starts up when the actor system fires up, which manages three children: `Fizz`, `Buzz` and `Foo`.

When `Master` starts up, that call to `doSomething()` can throw a `NoSuchElementException`. If it does, I would like the `Master` to shut down its three children, kill itself, shut down the actor system as a whole, and then invoke a custom system shutdown hook. My best attempt thus far:

```
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorRef master = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(Master.class));
        master.tell(new Init(), ActorRef.noSender()); 

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            void run() {
                System.out.println("Shutting down!");
            }
        });   
    }
}

public class Master extends AbstractActor {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private ActorRef fizz;
    private ActorRef buzz;
    private ActorRef foo;

    public Master() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
            .match(Init.class, init -> {
                try {
                    fizz = context().actorOf(Props.create(Fizz.class));
                    buzz = context().actorOf(Props.create(Buzz.class));
                    foo = context().actorOf(Props.create(Foo.class));

                    long metric = doSomething();

                    log.info("After all the children started up \"metric\" was: {}", metric);                    
                } catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
                    self().tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(), self());
                }
            }).build();
    }
}
```

My thinking here is:

- Since `Master` is the top-most actor, I can't define a `SupervisorStrategy` to handle the thrown `NoSuchElementException` for me, so I have to put a try-catch in there to handle it
- My *understanding* of `PoisonPill` is that it shuts down the receiving actor's children and then shuts the actor down
- However I'm still fuzzy as to whether `PoisonPill` shuts the actor system down *if* the actor happens to be the root/top-level actor, and I'm also not seeing how I can wire the `PoisonPill` to not only shut the actor system down, but also engage the JVM's shutdown hook

When I run this code I don't see any evidence of the actor system shutting down, it just hangs. Any ideas how I can wire all this together to achieve the desired affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired behavior is to have the master actor call `getContext().getSystem().terminate()` and register a callback that contains the shutdown logic with [`ActorSystem.registerOnTermination`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/actor/ActorSystem.html#registerOnTermination-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
actorSystem.registerOnTermination(new Runnable {
  @Override 
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Shutting down!");
  }
});

// ...

try {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
  getContext().getSystem().terminate();
}
```

[Coordinated shutdown](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#coordinated-shutdown) is available for shutdown procedures that are more involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the supervision strategy for the user guardian:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/supervision.html#user-the-guardian-actor

If you have the user guardian escalate any exceptions, then throw the NoSuchElementException, the exception will end up at the root guardian with the result that your system will exit.